# Cannot open one website in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet

I am having problems connecting to my host via my Windows 7 64-bit machine. I can connect to llhosts.com  from my XP Machine, plugged into the same switch, so I know it's not a router issue, I have tried disabling my firewall and sillt I

- Get a "connection error" when I try and browse to {llhosts.com,
  llpots.com, woodfire.com, etc}
- ping any of the above
- telnet to any of the above.

I can do any of those actions to any other website. AND I can do all of those to the sites hosted on host.llhosts.com on my XP machine as well.

Comment: Have you made sure that there is no software firewall installed on your Win7 machine that blocks the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my ip was being blocked at the server.  Had to get assistance from my hosting company.  They removed the deny host rule and now I'm in.

Answer (score 1):

Tried flushing your DNS cache by running ipconfig /flushdns from a command prompt?

Also, have you cleared out your browser cache totally?

How about disabling the site security features in IE8?